# What can be said about holomorphy and convergence radius of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+k}z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, power-series

Consider a function f(z) holomorphic in some neighbourhood of z = 0 expands at zero into
power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ with convergence radius R. Fix a natural number k. What can be said about holomorphy and convergence radius of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+k}z^n$?

I know that according to Cauchy-Hadamard theorem $lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac{1}{R}$, hence I want to find what is the $lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+k}|}$. I think it is a subsequence then it is the same limit but I'm not sure. Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You indeed already answered your question. The formula gives the same convergence radius, so holomorphy within the same open disc. When we look at an infinite sum, there is no problem of convergence for the first term but for infinity. What is the behavior when we sum infinitely many but since the two sequences of coefficients have the same behavior it is not surprising that the domain of convergence is the same. In fact we can also obtain your new expression as follows: let us call $f(z)$ your original function. Simply do $\big( f(z) - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_j\, z^j\big)/z^k$

Comment: (From the series viewpoint, holomorphy because the convergence is "normal", with norm=supremum on some disc)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
\begin{aligned}
|a_{n+k}|^{1/n}&=\exp\Big(\frac{1}{n}\log(|a_{n+k}|)\Big)\\
&=\exp\Big(\frac{n+k}{n}\frac{1}{n+k}\log(|a_{n+k}|)\Big)\\
&=\exp\Big(\frac{n+k}{n}\log\big(|a_{n+k}|^{1/(n+k)}\big)\Big)
\end{aligned}

From where it is easy to check that
$$\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+k}|}=\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$$
That is, the series you mention in the OP have the same radius of convergence, which is not surprising as some of the comments explain.